# Why does Matlab's ODE solvers require the function to be defined with two input arguments?

Tags: matlab, ode

```
function ydot = eq1(t,y)
ydot = cos(t);
```

This eq1 then gets passed to ode23 or ode45...if the y is not there in the inputs, it won't work...why is that? The y does appear anywhere in the body of the function.

Comment: What if your ODE was `ydot = y` (i.e., `y = a*exp(t)`) or  `ydot = y + t`?  MATLAB's ODE suite is [designed to solve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html#f1-753255) the general problems `ydot = f(t,y)`, `M * ydot = f(t,y)`, and `f(t,y,ydot) = 0`.

Comment: You're right, the solvers could be written to detect the single input argument case and assume that argument was `t` (a common pattern). However, the ODE suite is very old. It predates the existence of function handles and anonymous functions in Matlab and used to use strings to represent the names of functions (still a valid syntax, but slower, and poor style). My guess is that this strict requirement dates from the early versions too where (and when) it may have have been more complicated and slower to parse different input argument cases.

Comment: @horchler That's a good point on the function handle history.  Apparently it wasn't until R2012a that `nargin(fx)` was able to accept a handle-literal (strings only before that).  And while the requirement may be strict, I do think it is better to unambiguously require both `t` and `y` than to allow one and default to one or the other.